# Select latest record in the group with ordering

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am having trouble writing a query using Django ORM, I want to find the latest record in each group. I am putting chat messages in the model and I want to find the latest chat of each user and show chats latest chat of each user and with the latest user's chat on the home screen just like in WhatsApp, Skype or similar apps.  Currently, I am using the following query,

```
Chats.objects.all().order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id')
```

Using this I am able to get the latest chat of each user but I am not able to get the sequence correct. The result of the query is in the order of which the users were created in the database which I understand is correct, but I want to show the user who sent the latest chat at the top.

My `Models.py`

```
class Chats(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chat = models.CharField(max_length=1023, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thank you so much, Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Order on the Django/Python layer

The items are first sorted by `user_id`, and only in case of a tie, it takes the one with the latest date. But that means that you eventually get for each user a `Chats` object, *ordered by the `user_id`*.

I think here your only option is to sort it at the Django/Python level, so wrap it into a list, and sort by the `date`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

items = list(Chats.objects.order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id'))
items.sort(key=attrgetter('date'), reverse=True)
# work with items
```

and then render the `items` in the template.

---

## Option 2: Annotate the `User` model instead

Another option is to annotate the `User` model and thus work with a `QuerySet` of `User` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Max, OuterRef, Subquery

User.objects.filter(
    chats__isnull=False
).annotate(
    last_date=Max('chats__date'),
    last_message=Subquery(
        Chat.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date').value('chat')[:1]
    )
).order_by('-last_date')
```

Here the `User` objects will have an extra attribute `.last_date` with the latest date time of the object, and `.last_message` with that message.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: If he wants the user that sent the latest chat, shouldn't he just flip the prioritization of the order?

Or remove the user_id altogether?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much for replying, Will this not be very slow? As the number of users will increase at a very fast rate? I am also implementing pagination here.

Comment: @KeoniGarner: that will not work. The entire idea of the `.distinct('user_id')` in PostgreSQL is to sort first on the item for which you want to retrieve the latest item: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct it is a PostgreSQL-only feature.

Comment: @Dexter: the only other option is to annotate the `User` objects instead, and thus not rely on this PostgreSql-only feature, since it basically "abuses" sorting to get the latest item per group.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just had one last query if I try to use the query you provided but the query does not work for me as is but if I just change to Chat.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')[:1].values('pk','chat'), it works fine, can you please let me know if that is intended as I have not used Subquery very much in Django.

Comment: @Dexter: the `.values(..)` was indeed missing. Updated.